# Position of first word in a string in gfortran, use of character variables

Tags: fortran, character, gfortran

It seems quite simple, and I've drafted code to do it, but cannot for the life of me understand why it does not work.

```
character(len=120) ww
ww="   first_word   2nd_word     "
call locfw(ww,120,i1,i2)
write(6,*) ww(i1:i2)
stop
end

SUBROUTINE LOCFW(WW,NN,I1,I2)
!Returns location (I1:I2) of first word in string WW of length NN.
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: NN
INTEGER, INTENT(OUT) :: I1,I2
CHARACTER(LEN=NN),INTENT(IN) :: WW
INTEGER I
DO I=1,NN
  IF(WW(I).NE." ") THEN
    I1=I
    EXIT
  ENDIF
ENDDO
DO I=I1+1,NN
  IF(WW(I).EQ." ") THEN
     I2=I-1
     EXIT
   ENDIF
ENDDO
RETURN
END
```

It is probably something simple that is wrong, but although I've coded in Fortran for years my knowledge of handling characters is quite limited.  (Usually focused on numbers.)

Comment: If you think the link does not answer your question it is essential to properly describe your problem. Saying *"it does not work"* does not say anything useful. We need to hear what is wrong explicitely.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.  I understand now that the reference the I the character is a string "WW", I must use  WW(I:I) and not just W(I).  With that, and some other changes that enabled me to simplify it a bit I managed to get the code to compile.  Sometimes, when trying something I have little experience, I can easily go down the wrong track when looking for bugs, since I may not be 100% confident about the code or my  interpretation of the manual.